# Applescript to watch if chrome tab crashes

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Is it possible to watch chrome with an applescript and if a tab fails and crashes to automatically reload the tab?

Answer (score 2):

Try saving a script like this as a stay open application:

```
on idle
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat with t in tabs of windows
            tell t
                try
                    with timeout of 0.1 seconds
                        execute javascript "document"
                    end timeout
                on error
                    reload
                end try
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
    return 60
end idle
```

You can start the application at login by adding it to login items. It can be terminated with `killall applet`. You could also remove the idle handler and run the script with [cron or launchd](https://superuser.com/a/443641/69039).

To test the script, you can force a tab to crash by running this in the JavaScript console:

```
x="a";while(1){x+=x}
```